# Overload GWT Date_CustomFieldSerializer

Tags: date, gwt, overloading, serialization

I'm trying to overload the GWT "Date_CustomFieldSerializer" ( GWT 2.5.1 with maven2 and java1.6 ).

I've read that it is possible to overload a serializer by creating the same package structure inside your own project.

In my case I reproduce the package `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util` to overload the class `Date_CustomFieldSerializer` but it does not seem to work well.

When serializing the Date, GWT `Date_CustomSerializer` is used but when the Date is deserialized my own "Date_CustomSerializer" is used.

If I delete the compiled `Date_CustomFieldSerializer.class` off `gwt-user.jar` and `gwt-servlet.jar` then my own `Date_CustomFieldSerializer` is always used but this is a bad solution, I am after a clean way to say to GWT that uses my own serializer always.

For delvelopment I use jetty and maven with the gwt-maven-plugin and in production mode I use weblogic.

I try to compile my own version of GWT but it fails when I try to run it, the server says:

```
[ERROR] Unable to initialize static dispatcher
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject$ : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

How can I set it up to use my own serializer without GWT custom compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Is your version first on the classpath?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. My own class is inside WEB-INF/classes and the GWT class is inside WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet.jar. So I think that my own class has te correct preference but something is wrong

Answer (score 0):

It'a the version of Java.
You must compile the GWT Jar and your class with the same version of java.
The version 51 is the Java 7 version. ([How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0))
But the GWT must be compiled with java 6.
You must set your java source to 1.6

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. My java version is "1.6.0_29". I compiled GWT with ant 1.8.3 and java 1.6. It's very strange because I don't use java 7

Comment: I had this problem with eclipse, maybe your IDE is build your classes with Java 1.7 ?

Comment: Hi, but I don't import the project inside eclipse. I only change one class with edit++ and them I run ant inside a console, and I verify that in teh console I have java 1.6 with ant 1.8.3